# recycle long-running process on iis 7

Tags: iis-7, process

is there a way to limit long-running processes in iis 7? for example, if I have ASP.NET application and it takes longer than 10 minutes to generate response, I want it recycled.

how can I configure this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the Advanced Settings for your Application Pool. Either the "Ping Enabled" or "Shutdown Time Limit" options in the Process Model section could be what you are looking for. Here is the configuration reference for Process Model from iis.net:

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/processModel

Comment: the process responses to the ping, but if I try to manually recycle the pool, it gets terminated, since it can't shutdown gracefully because it's still working on generating a response.

Comment: If it is still responding to pings, you probably need to look at the shutdown time limit rather than the ping option. If the app pool is still actively processing information though, I don't think anything will be able to shut it down cleanly.